# not able to understand the execution of sortpath column in this SQL code

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetSubtree(@mgr AS INT, @maxlevels AS INT = NULL)
  RETURNS TABLE
  WITH SCHEMABINDING
  AS
   RETURN
    WITH EmpsCTE AS
      (
       SELECT empid, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS mgrid, empname, salary, 0 as lvl,
           CAST(‘.’ AS VARCHAR(900)) AS sortpath
           FROM dbo.Employees
            WHERE empid = @mgr
  UNION ALL
   SELECT S.empid, S.mgrid, S.empname, S.salary, M.lvl + 1 AS lvl,
      CAST(M.sortpath + CAST(S.empid AS VARCHAR(10)) + ‘.’ AS VARCHAR(900)) 
      AS sortpath
         FROM EmpsCTE AS M
          INNER JOIN dbo.Employees AS S
            ON S.mgrid = M.empid
           AND (M.lvl < @maxlevels OR @maxlevels IS NULL)
            )
            SELECT empid, mgrid, empname, salary, lvl, sortpath
             FROM EmpsCTE;
```

This is my function in SQL server but when i execute this using below query i am not able to understand the output of sortpath column

```
SELECT empid, REPLICATE(‘ | ‘, lvl) + empname AS emp,
        mgrid, salary, lvl, sortpath
       FROM dbo.GetSubtree(3, NULL) AS T
        ORDER BY sortpath;
```

then the output is

```
empid empname        mgrid  salary   lvl sortpath
------ ----------------- ------ -------- ---- -----------
  3     Ina           NULL  7500.00   0     .
  7     | Aaron       3     5000.00   1     .7.
  11    | | Gabriel   7     3000.00   2     .7.11.
  9     | | Rita      7     3000.00   2     .7.9.
  12    | | | Emilia  9     2000.00   3     .7.9.12.
  13    | | | Michael 9     2000.00   3     .7.9.13.
  14    | | | Didi    9     1500.00   3     .7.9.14.
```

now from my perspective the row which has empid 11 should only have .11. otput of sortpath can anyone me with this execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> from my perspective the row which has empid 11 should only have .11. otput of sortpath

Why do you think that? Each employee is joined to their manager and extends their manager's `sortpath` with their own employee id and a `.`. Since 11's manager is `7`, and `7`'s sort path is `.7.`, why do you not expect the `7` to be there?

If this is, as its name suggests, intended to be used for sorting, I'd be using `/` as the separators instead of `.`. I'd also include the top level manager's `id` in their sort path, and finally I'd cast this column to [`hierarchyid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-2017) in the final output from the function. This would then properly sort `/3/7/11/` *after* `/3/7/9/` (unlike your output) because it doesn't just rely on lexicographical sort order.

e.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetSubtree(@mgr AS INT, @maxlevels AS INT = NULL)
  RETURNS TABLE
  WITH SCHEMABINDING
  AS
   RETURN
    WITH EmpsCTE AS
      (
       SELECT empid, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS mgrid, empname, salary, 0 as lvl,
           CAST('/' + s.empid + '/' AS VARCHAR(900)) AS sortpath
           FROM dbo.Employees
            WHERE empid = @mgr
  UNION ALL
   SELECT S.empid, S.mgrid, S.empname, S.salary, M.lvl + 1 AS lvl,
      CAST(M.sortpath + CAST(S.empid AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/' AS VARCHAR(900)) 
      AS sortpath
         FROM EmpsCTE AS M
          INNER JOIN dbo.Employees AS S
            ON S.mgrid = M.empid
           AND (M.lvl < @maxlevels OR @maxlevels IS NULL)
            )
            SELECT empid, mgrid, empname, salary, lvl,
               CAST(sortpath as hierarchyid) as sortpath
             FROM EmpsCTE;
```

Comment: as the manager shortpath has only '.' sperator used (M.sortpath will always give me .) right??

Comment: @PrashantChaturvedi - look at the output again. Employee 7s sortpath is `.7.`. We are always joining (in the recursive part of the CTE) the direct manager to those who report to them. So when processing the row for employee 11, `M` refers to the row for employee 7.